# How does the Doctor avoid changing the history of the future?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

Given that the Doctor is careful about not changing *established* history when travelling into the *past* [certainly the First Doctor in the Aztecs was quite adamant that history couldn't be changed, though this view softened and the concept of "fixed points in time" was introduced], how does he ensure that he isn't going to change the established history of the times even further in the future of the period he is in [in the tenth Doctor's second story the Doctor wouldn't attempt to save the Earth from being destroyed]? Namely, if he travels to the future, this future is someone else's past.

Comment: It's not super clear what you asking here. Maybe add an example from the show and elaborate on what you mean. :)

Comment: [*"People assume that time is a strict progression of cause to effect, but **actually** from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint - it's more like a big ball of wibbly wobbly... time-y wimey... stuff."*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2nNzNo_Xps)

Comment: The Doctor's opinions on what he can or cannot safely, morally, and/or possibly change about history varies wildly depending on what era of the show and what plot arc we're talking about. Some of that variance even has in-universe justification. But you'll have to pick a specific example of this variance before I can go looking for an explanation for it; covering every example in Doctor Who history is just too much for one post.

Comment: @Ixrec - Not least because it varies wildly between writers even within a series.

Comment: When the Doctor plays a major role in events in the future, it's probably for the same sorts of reasons he feels free to play a major role in events in the past (as he has done many times), because he either knows that a particular alien invasion or other disaster is "supposed" to fail (in the version of history he's familiar with, the civilization being invaded did not permanently fall at that date), or because neither outcome would contradict his knowledge, or in the newer series, because he knows the outcome is not a "fixed point" and is thus OK to mess with.

Comment: You lost me at "the Doctor is careful about changing established history."

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me the Doctor's attitude is usually "If I know it'll be changing history in a major way, I can't do it.  If I don't know, or it's a minor enough change that could be wrapped up as 'historical inaccuracy', it's okay to change it, since chances are I'm part of what's supposed to have happened."

Comment: @starpilotsix Except when that giant Cyberman tromps through Victorian London.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I found his idea for the Trojan Horse much more intriguing.

Comment: I always thought it is a time-lord thing. I mean their race might be capable of somehow sensing the _so-called **fixed points**_ of time-space. (The Doctor keeps referring to those as unchangeable/volatile and anything else as dynamic.)

Comment: Is it safe to say that the TV Show doesn't follow any coherent rules on time travel?

Answer (score 1):

While I was looking up some examples, came across this on the Wiki page for Kill the Moon: "In "The Fires of Pompeii", the Tenth Doctor says that as a Time Lord, he can see both fixed and mutable points in time. The Twelfth Doctor says the same thing here, but that there are "grey areas", points in time for which he cannot see the outcome.", with a link (and this is just my point of view, perhaps a little unfairly since there were some good moments, misnamed) to the [site](http://www.doctorwhotv.co.uk/12-great-moments-from-kill-the-moon-67452.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit of evidence from the show that the Doctor has been to points in time from every period of the Universe, across multiple alternate timelines, collecting information as he goes. Consider that his relationship to River Song across the ages proceeded backwards in time from their first meeting, for instance. The history of Gallifrey before its fall occurred very far in the future from present-day Earth, and may even be connected to present-day Earth's fate in the far future. So almost everything in *our* future consists of events in the *past* from the Doctor's perspective, and even then they go towards the end of the Universe, time-wise, the Doctor appears to have the same concerns about not disrupting events that are supposed to make history (in the far future), unless he is prophesied to have been part of those events (which he often is).

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to look at this more four-dimensionally.

"The history of the future" is going to be relative to any one person at any one time. Technically, everything we do right now "changes" the future in some way, up to and including whether or not I finish replying to this post. But since we don't know anything about the future, we've no idea how we're changing things.

So for The Doctor, everything (s)he does affects events past the point that (s)he arrives.

(That's gonna get tiring - let's go with "she", shall we?)

If she knows nothing about the future of any one person (from someone she saves to one of her companions), she's got no idea what she's doing to the future. In the case of, say, Adelaide Brooke and the staff of Bowie Base One, The Doctor knew damn well who they were, and what was to happen, knew not to do anything to save them, and did it anyway.

One of the best examples of affecting "the future" was the Hartnell adventure *The Ark*. They arrive on a generation ship twice, many years apart, and the results of their first visit (leaving behind a cold virus) had catastrophic effects on the people of the ship by the time of their second visit.  *The Face of Evil* is another example - bad computer programming resulted in societal upheaval.

So to summarize, The Doctor only seems to worry about how she's affecting things when she's AWARE of what the future of those things are. If she's no idea, she works under the assumption that having good people not die is the best strategy.

(Hope you enjoy being in this post completed comment timeline)